# build java database program from console

Tags: java, oracle

How can I make available ojdbc14.jar on running java command?

Comment: I know the JDBC Connectivity in Java Programs but don't know how to run JDBC Program from console. So, that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn how to access an Oracle database from Java, read the [JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).

About your second question: you'll have to add `ojdbc14.jar` to the [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) when you run your application, for example by using the `-cp` option:

```
java -cp C:\Some\Dir\ojdbc14.jar;C:\Project\MyClasses org.mypackage.MyProgram
```

Comment: `ojdbc14.jar` is a *very* old driver. Current (up-to-date) drivers have the filename `ojdbc6.jar`